# DHCPd and DHCPc on different UDP port?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

Is it possible to create a run another custom dhcp service on different UDP port.

For example port 70 and 71?

Therefore all my clients pre-configured to accept this instruction and if fails fall back to official dhcp port?

Comment: What are the client systems?

Answer (score 3):

ISC [dhcpd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/dhcpd.8.html#contenttoc5) and [dhclient](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/dhclient.8.html#contenttoc5) both accept `-p` options to use a different port number (you'd have to check that all the clients you use support this). You would need to implement the fallback yourself though (i.e. create a wrapper script which launches `dhclient` on the custom port and then launches it on the standard port if it doesn't get a lease).